# How to select rows only in specific years in `timestamp` fields

Tags: node.js, postgresql

How to select rows only in specific years (q1) or years and months (q2) in `timestamp` fields with postgresql

table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "Article"(
"ArticleId" SERIAL NOT NULL,
"ReleaseDate" timestamp without time zone,
...

PRIMARY KEY ("ArticleId")
);
```

code(with nodejs)

q1

```
var releaseDateY = [2015,1990];

// ??
// var query = 'SELECT * FROM "Article" WHERE "ReleaseDate" IN (';
// for (var i = 0; i < releaseDateY.length; i++) {
//   if (i > 0) {
//     query += ',';
//   }
//   query += '$' + (i + 1);
// }
// query += ')';

var params = releaseDateY;
```

q2

```
var releaseDateY = [2015,1990];
var releaseDateM = [1,3];

// ??
// var query = 'SELECT * FROM "Article" WHERE "ReleaseDate" IN (';
// for (var i = 0; i < releaseDateY.length; i++) {
//   if (i > 0) {
//     query += ',';
//   }
//   query += '$' + (i + 1);
// }
// query += ')';

// var ii = i;
// for (var i = 0; i < releaseDateM.length; i++) {
//   if (i > 0) {
//     query += ',';
//   }
//   query += '$' + (i + 1);
// }
// query += ')';

var params = [];
params.push(releaseDateY);
params.push(releaseDateM);
// params [2015,1990,1,3]
```

Comment: `where extract(year from releasedate) in (2012,2013,2014)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for reply and if like q2 need to select in year also in month how to do it

Comment: `extract(month from releasedate) = 1`: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  like this ? `WHERE extract(year from "ReleaseDate") IN (2012,2013)  AND extract(month from "ReleaseDate") IN (1,12)`

Comment: it works!! thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

I know 2 functions that can be used: **to_char**, **extract**

```
select to_char(now(), 'YYYY')
select extract(year from now())
```

But you may have a problem if you use them in where clause. You need to make functional index in that case. Try to use explain to see results.